# HomeKit Accessory Simulator "Accessory is not reachable" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, homekit

I am building a HomeKit application with Xcode and simulator on iOS 10, and I am using HomeKit Accessory Simulator to simulate accessories. but after I invoke  addAccessory:completionHandler method, it gives me error 4: "Accessory is not reachable".

BTW, in iOS simulator, I do have the "accessory is not certified" dialog appears, And I can click on "Add Anyway", but there is no dialog to enter setup code.

Xcode version: 8.1
HomeKit Accessory Simulator version:2.0 (108.2)
iOS Simulator and HomeKit Simulator are running on the same machine

code to add accessory:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToAccessoryList:(UIStoryboardSegue* )segue {
NewAccessoryTableViewController* sourceController = [segue sourceViewController];
if(sourceController.accessoryItemArray.count > 0) {
    for(AccessoryItem* item in sourceController.accessoryItemArray) {
        if(item.selected) {
            // add selected item to home
            [self.home addAccessory:item.accessory completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if(error) {
                    NSLog(@"AccessoryTableViewController:addAccessory(), error adding accessory to home, error:%@", error);
                }
            }];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}
```

And the error log I got:

```
2016-11-16 10:41:30.623 LearnIOSApp2[1855:39742] AccessoryTableViewController:addAccessory(), error adding accessory to home, error:Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=4 "Accessory is not reachable." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Accessory is not reachable.}
```

Great thanks for help!